# Postman do not recognize function

Tags: typescript, postman

Im doing a program where I create vehicles and  and I save them in mongoDB.
I used postman and post a vehicle but i got this error messagem "**Vehicle.create is not a function**".

```
 public async createVehicle(vehicleDTO: IVehicleDTO): Promise<Result<IVehicleDTO>> {
try {

  const vehicleOrError = await Vehicle.create(vehicleDTO);

  if (vehicleOrError.isFailure) {
    return Result.fail<IVehicleDTO>(vehicleOrError.errorValue());
  }

  const vehicleResult = vehicleOrError.getValue();

  await this.vehicleRepo.save(vehicleResult);

  const vehicleDTOResult = VehicleMap.toDTO( vehicleResult ) as IVehicleDTO;
  return Result.ok<IVehicleDTO>( vehicleDTOResult )
} catch (e) {
  throw e;
}
```

}

The create function is :

```
public static create (vehicleDTO: IVehicleDTO, id?: UniqueEntityID): Result<Vehicle> {

const vid = VehicleID.create(vehicleDTO.id);
if(vid.isFailure){
  return Result.fail<Vehicle>(vid.error);
}

const desc = VehicleDescription.create(vehicleDTO.desc);
if(desc.isFailure){
  return Result.fail<Vehicle>(desc.error);
} 

const fuel = Fuel.create(vehicleDTO.fuel);
if(fuel.isFailure){
  return Result.fail<Vehicle>(fuel.error);
}

const auto = Autonomy.create(vehicleDTO.auto);
if(auto.isFailure){
  return Result.fail<Vehicle>(auto.error);
}

const avgC = AvgConsumption.create(vehicleDTO.avgC);
if(avgC.isFailure){
  return Result.fail<Vehicle>(avgC.error);
}

const avgV = AvgVelocity.create(vehicleDTO.avgV);
if(avgV.isFailure){
  return Result.fail<Vehicle>(avgV.error);
}

const cost = CostKm.create(vehicleDTO.cost);
if(cost.isFailure){
  return Result.fail<Vehicle>(cost.error);
}

    const vehicle = new Vehicle({
      desc: desc.getValue(), fuel: fuel.getValue(), auto: auto.getValue(), avgC: avgC.getValue(), avgV: avgV.getValue(), 
      cost: cost.getValue(),id: vid.getValue()}, id);

    return Result.ok<Vehicle>(vehicle);
  
}
```

I really dont understand why postman is sendind this error message, when "create" is clearly a function.

Comment: Postman has nothing to do with it. How are you importing/defining `Vehicle` ?

Comment: @Evert I'm creating it directely in postman with json

Comment: @Evert thanks for the time but i manage to solve it. I named a variable "Vehicle" and the program used it instead the Class Vehicle. rooky mistake